# Django looping records to match ID issue, other options?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I send an SMS messages via a gateway and get a reply with a reference ID for the SMS.

```
12345678-2
```

I store this in my database.

The the gateway then calls a URL on my server with a delivery receipt and the ID of the text it belongs to...

```
12345678
```

Notice the difference! So here is the issue I need to match the ID to the ID in my DB. For some reason this particular gateway only sends back the first part of the ID omitting everything after the dash `-`

I first idea was to just strip the ID in the database without the dash before storing, but this is **not** an option for me as need to store the whole thing. Other gateways uses this code I cannot change this function.

My second option was to match the ID like below by loop ALL records.

```
class MessageManager(models.Manager):
    def get_matching_message(self, ref_ID):
        for gateway in Gateway.objects.all():
            try:
                return Message.objects.get(
                    gateway_message_id=ref_ID
                )
            except Message.DoesNotExist:
                pass
```

But I cannot bring myself to do this, **it smells bad**!

I'm open to other ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Is it possible for the SMS id to be duplicated? Ie. other gateways can create the same id?

Comment: @limelights possible but improbable it's a UUID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the gateways stores duplicates in your database then this code could help you:

```
class MessageManager(models.Manager):
    def get_matching_messages(self, ref_id):
        try:
            return Message.objects.filter(gateway_message_id__icontains=ref_id)
        except Message.DoesNotExist:
            pass
```

This will produce a Queryset and not return just 1 object.

Otherwise switch `filter()` for `get()` and use `__iexact` which will return 1 object and throw a `MultipleObjectsReturned` exception if you have duplicates.

```
class MessageManager(models.Manager):
    def get_matching_messages(self, ref_id):
        try:
            return Message.objects.get(gateway_message_id__iexact=ref_id)
        except (Message.DoesNotExist, Message.MultipleObjectsReturned):
            pass
```

Since you're not using anything from the `gateway` iteration this could now be skipped unless this `gateway_message_id=ref_ID` should be `gateway.message_id=ref_ID` (notice the .)
But it's hard to tell without seeing your models.

I don't believe this smells but I see where you're coming from, you're facing an issue which you cannot "fix" since other gateways depends on the same code and that makes it, hmmm, a nuisance to say the least.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, just the sort of information I needed.